# how I fetch all data from multiple tables using subquery in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fetch data using postgressql using inner join but I am getting only the matching rows:

```
select r.name, r.description, tags.name tags, rb.ingredient_id, mb.name macros 
from recipe r 
inner join recipe_tags tags on r.id = tags.recipe_id 
inner join recipe_breakdown rb on tags.recipe_id = rb.recipe_id 
inner join recipe_master_breakdown mb on rb.recipe_id = mb.recipe_id 
limit 50
```

here it is giving only the matching rows, but I want to fetch all the data from the tables either by subquery or any other joins.

Please help me for solving this.

Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: use `left join` ?

Comment: or `full join`?

Comment: @VvdL that is also giving only matching rows

Answer (score 0):

Did you really try the left joins (like Vvdl said)? The whole idea behind inner joins is that you only see matches. This should yield all results:

```
select r.name, r.description, tags.name tags, rb.ingredient_id, mb.name macros 
from recipe r 
left join recipe_tags tags on r.id = tags.recipe_id 
left join recipe_breakdown rb on tags.recipe_id = rb.recipe_id 
left join recipe_master_breakdown mb on rb.recipe_id = mb.recipe_id
```